# Square Cam's View not shown cameraview

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avcam, camera-overlay

I refer the squareCam example of apple's development library it works fine.

But

When i try to change overlay image on one button click like this

```
square = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add"];
[self teardownAVCapture];
[self setupAVCapture];
```

on button click i use this code to change the image and show as overlay.

but i don't know what the problem is but i have to click twice to show the cameraview as first time it just shows black screen.

Help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you use `square`? Your provided code isn't explaining anything.

Comment: it is example from apple development site see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190) example as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. Have to make some changes in the method below shown as I am uses **ARC** in **iOS5**.

```
- (void)teardownAVCapture
{
    [session stopRunning];
    session = nil;
    videoDataOutput = nil;
    dispatch_release(videoDataOutputQueue);
    [stillImageOutput removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"capturingStillImage"];
    stillImageOutput = nil;
    previewLayer = nil;
    [previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```